# selenium - select a column by header

Tags: java, selenium, indexing, html-table

In my script (selenium & Java) I need to select a table column by it's header.
Basically, I send the header as a parameter and then just fetch through that column.

But, the problem is that I'm not able to get the header column's index. 
Any idea or suggestion?

```
 <table class="table table-hover tablesorter ib-table" data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0">
<thead data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0.0">
<tr data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0.0.0">
<th data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0.0.0.0">ID</th>
<th data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0.0.0.1">To</th>
<th data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0.0.0.2">From</th>
<th data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0.0.0.3">Text</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0.1" style="height: auto;">
<tr data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0.1.$0">
<td data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0.1.$0.0">123456</td>
<td data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0.1.$0.1">+0156477889785</td>
<td data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0.1.$0.2">+0156477889784</td>
<td data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0.1.$0.3">sample textM</td>
</tr>
<tr data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0.1.$1">
<tr data-reactid=".0.0.0.1.2.0.1.$2">
```

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you provide `html` code sample for the same and `java` code that you've tried already

Answer (score 0):

First you need to do a List that has all the headers by

```
List<WebElement> headersList = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table-hover tablesorter ib-table']")).findElements(By.tagName("th"));
```

after that you going threw all the tr in loop

```
List<WebElement> trList = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table-hover tablesorter ib-table']")).findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

List<WebElement> tdList;

for(int = i ; i < trList.Count ; i++)
{
tdList = trList[i].findElements(By.tagName("td"));

//tdList[0] its header in index[0]... and so on...
}
```

Comment: interesting, but it's not possible to get the index without that? I mean. there is no a property .index=...

Comment: you can to it by path like: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table-hover tablesorter ib-table']//th[1]")).getText; if its helping

Answer (score 0):

This will not work in odd cases such as when using colspan. It should work for any "normal" table of data. The trim is in use for avoiding the inevitable whitespace that appears around many WebElements.

```
public static List<WebElement> getColumnByHeaderText(WebDriver driver, By by, String header) {
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(by);
    Function<WebElement, String> elementToString = (WebElement w) -> w.getText().trim();
    List<WebElement> list = table.findElements(By.tagName("th"));
    int index = Lists.transform(list, elementToString).indexOf(header);
    if (index == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to locate header");
    } else {
        return table.findElements(By.cssSelector("td:nth-child(" + (index + 1 ) + ")"));
    }
}
```